# 3D plot from 1×n(one column) vector

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to Plot 3D figure from a 1×n(column vector) containing numeric data. I have used ListPlot3D but its not working as I need to convert 1×n(column vector) vector into n×n matrix first then I can use the command

```
ListPlot3D[{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},…}]
```

Please guide me how I can convert first 1×n(column vector) into a matrix of order n×n or is there any other way to get 3D plot in Mathematica. I am very new on Mathematica programming. Need your's help to sort out my problem. Highly Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your column vector contains groups of three values that constitute the coordinates of the surface points. In the simplest case, these values are contiguous. In that case, simply use "Partition", like so:

[image]

If more rearranging is necessary, use the tools for rearranging lists, as shown here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RearrangingAndRestructuringLists.html

Comment: HaraldCoder- this is not the case. I have one column vector of order  1×n. I want a matrix in which each column of the matrix contains this column vector. So as a result i will get a matrix of order n×n.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Please provide more information. Also: how would you want to use ListPlot3D on a nxn matrix?

Comment: "I have one column vector of order 1×n. I want a matrix in which each column of the matrix contains this column vector. So as a result i will get a matrix of order n×n" One interpretation where n = 5. Example vector `x = RandomInteger[100, 5]`. 5x5 matrix where each column is x: Table[x, 5] // Transpose.

Comment: HaraldCoder i have a column vector. How can i get 3D plot from this numeric data of column vetcor. this is the question

Comment: @HaraldCoder The question is too vague. Please provide an example of the column vector and which elements of the vector correspond to the x, y, z values.

Comment: @Mike: ListPlot3D takes a list of 3D coordinates, as in the example in my answer, or an array of height values. So, making a table from the vector, like Rohit shows, works, with any number greater than 1 in place of the example 5 - but that contains no more information than a 2D plot of the vector. So, other than for optical reasons, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @HaraldCoder Oops, my comment was intended for Mike, not you. Sorry about that.